# Building a VGG Face model in TF: Running into shape mismatch and unsupported shape errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Question: How do I set up a CNN so that the shapes match? It's my first time working with one since my background is in NLP, and I'm running into the error that says the shapes don't match.

What I've tried:

1. I've tried editing the filters and kernel_size variables.
2. I think kernel_size is correct. I've tried setting the filters variable to tf.constant(kernel).shape[-1] and tf.constant(kernel).shape[-2]. It seems to me that there aren't any other options, so I'm confused, although I think this is where the problem is.

Input weights matrix:

1. [http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/vgg_face/](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/software/vgg_face/)
2. Download vgg_face_matconvnet.tar.gz and upzip.
3. vgg_face_matconvnet/Data/vgg_face.mat

Code:

```
# read layer info
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input([224, 224, 3]))
for layer in layers:
    layer_type = layer[0][0][0][0]
    name = layer[0][0][1][0]
    if layer_type == 'conv':
        print(layer_type)
        print(name)
        weights = layer[0][0][2][0]
        stride = layer[0][0][3][0]
        # pad =  layer[0][0][4][0]
        learningRate = layer[0][0][5][0]
        weightDecay = layer[0][0][6][0]
        momentum = layer[0][0][7][0]
        kernel, bias = weights
        # kernel = np.transpose(kernel, (1, 0, 2, 3))
        bias = np.squeeze(bias).reshape(-1)
        filters = tf.constant(kernel).shape[-1]
        kernel_size = (3,3) #[np.shape(kernel)[-3], np.shape(kernel)[-2]]
        bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(bias)
        strides=[1, stride[0]]
        if name[:2] == 'fc':
            padding = 'VALID'
            if name == 'fc6':
                model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
                dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(filters, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel))
            if name == 'fc7':
                dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(filters, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel))
            model.add(dense_layer)
        else:
            padding = 'SAME'
            conv2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel))
            model.add(conv2d_layer)
        print(f"{name} stride: {stride} kernel size: {np.shape(kernel)}")        
    elif layer_type == 'relu':
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0, threshold=0))
        print(name)
    elif layer_type == 'pool':
        pool = layer[0][0][3][0]
        stride = layer[0][0][4][0]
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool, strides=(stride[0],stride[0]), padding='SAME', data_format="channels_last"))
        print(f"{name} stride: {stride}")
    elif layer_type == 'softmax':
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Softmax())
        print(name)
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: Eager execution of tf.constant with unsupported shape (value has 102760448 elements, shape is (2048, 4096) with 8388608 elements).
```

Comment: Are you running the code on Google Colab?

Comment: @HaardikDharma yes

Comment: @pr338 Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct padding for the convolutional layers and this causes the layer output shapes to be not what is expected.

The output of the last `MaxPool2D` has shape `(None, 2, 2, 512)`, and when you flatten this you have 2048 input nodes to the `Dense` layer `fc6`. You create the Dense layer to have 4096 nodes, so the expected weight matrix has shape `(2048, 4096) = 8388608` values. However the weight matrix that you read in from the .mat file has much more values and is actually expecting 25088 input nodes and this causes an error.

Modify you code like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input([224, 224, 3]))
for layer in layers:
    layer_type = layer[0][0][0][0]
    name = layer[0][0][1][0]
    if layer_type == 'conv':
        print(layer_type)
        print(name)
        weights = layer[0][0][2][0]
        stride = layer[0][0][3][0]
        # pad =  layer[0][0][4][0]
        learningRate = layer[0][0][5][0]
        weightDecay = layer[0][0][6][0]
        momentum = layer[0][0][7][0]
        kernel, bias = weights
        # kernel = np.transpose(kernel, (1, 0, 2, 3))
        bias = np.squeeze(bias).reshape(-1)
        filters = tf.constant(kernel).shape[-1]
        kernel_size = (3,3) #[np.shape(kernel)[-3], np.shape(kernel)[-2]]
        bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(bias)
        strides=[1, stride[0]]
        if name[:2] == 'fc':
            # padding = 'VALID' # <-- not needed, Dense layers do not use padding
            if name == 'fc6':
                model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
                dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(filters, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel))
            if name == 'fc7':
                dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(filters, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel))
            model.add(dense_layer)
        else:
            padding = 'SAME'
            conv2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding=padding, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel)) # <--- padding = 'same' so that output shape is the same as input shape!
            model.add(conv2d_layer)
        print(f"{name} stride: {stride} kernel size: {np.shape(kernel)}")        
    elif layer_type == 'relu':
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0, threshold=0))
        print(name)
    elif layer_type == 'pool':
        pool = layer[0][0][3][0]
        stride = layer[0][0][4][0]
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=pool, strides=(stride[0],stride[0]), padding='SAME', data_format="channels_last"))
        print(f"{name} stride: {stride}")
    elif layer_type == 'softmax':
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Softmax())
        print(name)
```

This way the weights are imported correctly.